# Why is it necessary to clarify my variables are global in this instance?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

So I threw together a chore assigner program. Each time you run it, it will randomly split the chores between my roommate and I. No chore gets assigned to the same person more than 2 weeks in a row. Anyways, I struggled to get this working as this is my first python project but I think it runs perfectly now.

My question is, inside my choreAssign() function, if I don't clarify my variables as global I get an 'unresolved reference' error for lines 50-55. Why is that? (keep in mind I'm still new/learning and all my research hasn't made an answer apparent).

The entire code is below. A big huge comment in the code is clarifying where line 50 starts. My code is relatively short so I thought it would be okay to post the whole thing. This is my first post on this website (or any site like it) so I'm sorry if some etiquette is lacking.

```
import random

chores = ("Shower", "Kitchen counters", "Floors", "Toilet", "Mirror and Sink", "Tables/Laundry", "Garden", "Fan")

# Chore lists to be assigned this week
nick_chores1 = []
raul_chores1 = []
# Chore list for last week
nick_chores2 = []
raul_chores2 = []
# Chore list for week before last
nick_chores3 = []
raul_chores3 = []
# Extra chores that have already been repeated the last two weeks
chores_extra = []


def choreAssign():
    # GLOBAL VALUES IN QUESTION
    global nick_chores3
    global nick_chores2
    global raul_chores3
    global raul_chores2

    local_chores = list(chores)

    y = len(local_chores)
    while len(nick_chores1) < y / 2:
        random_chore = random.choice(local_chores)
        if len(nick_chores3) > 0:
            if nick_chores2.count(random_chore) + nick_chores3.count(random_chore) < 2:
                nick_chores1.append(random_chore)
                local_chores.remove(random_chore)
            else:
                chores_extra.append(random_chore)
                local_chores.remove(random_chore)
        else:
            nick_chores1.append(random_chore)
            local_chores.remove(random_chore)

    print(chores_extra)
    raul_chores1.extend(local_chores)
    raul_chores1.extend(chores_extra)
    local_chores.clear()
    chores_extra.clear()

    print("Nick's chores for the week are: " + str(nick_chores1))
    print("Raul's chores for the week are: " + str(raul_chores1))


# LINE 50 STARTS AFTER THESE COMMENTS. The below comment just clarifies what I'm trying to do with these few lines of code
    # the below 6 lines move the weekly data back one week (ex week 2 moves to week 3)

    nick_chores3 = nick_chores2[:]
    raul_chores3 = raul_chores2[:]
    nick_chores2 = nick_chores1[:]
    raul_chores2 = raul_chores1[:]
    nick_chores1.clear()
    raul_chores1.clear()

    x = input('Type "New" to assign a new weeks worth of chores: ').upper()
    if x == "NEW":
        choreAssign()


choreAssign()
```

Comment: Because assignment to a variable makes it local by default. You shouldn't be using global variables here anyway